# Css properties as falsie values in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-in-js

I'm looking for the answer to the question how should I use conditional styles with conditional operators.

What code example would be the best? Can we use non css values?

```js
margin: isOpen ? '10px' : undefined
```

```js
margin: isOpen ? '10px' : 'initial'
```

[image]

Is it okay to use it in that way? (so we pass 'undefined' and 'null' as a css property)

```js
margin: isOpen ?? '10px'
```

and one more (so we pass every falsie value)

```js
margin: isOpen && '10px'
```

or maybe this

```js
margin: isOpen ? '10px' : ''
```

As context we can say we wanna use it in react `style` porp, or in `styled-components`

Comment: Make sense to use 'initial' in that case because it is css supported value for this property. But is it bad to use: '', false, null, undefined, none?